# Repairing a git repository after blindly using sed on all files

Tags: git

I've tried using sed to change all files in my git repository (I've hit Control-C after realizing that it is changing the git files). Now I get this message when trying to commit:

```
$ commit -a
fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied
```

What can I do? Changing the files back would be rather difficult (I've been trying to replace all the occurrences of string `a` with string `b`, but `b` was already occurring in many files).

I don't have any backup of the repository.

**EDIT:** Actually I have one, but it's screwed up in a similar way (I did this to test something and didn't use it as a git repository afterwards).

Comment: at this point.... `git clone` from your upstream repo (if you have one) and start where ever you left off. Anything that manually edits the .git folder blindly will probably not be easily recoverable...

Comment: @g19fanatic: I don't have one, unfortunately.

Comment: @user2656304: Than I fear it is international backup awareness day.

Comment: The "Permission denied" seems odd. What's the output of `ls -ld .git .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: yeah, the file mode got changed for some reason.

Comment: @user2656304: Hmm, `sed` by itself shouldn't do that. *If* this is recoverable, one step would be create a new repository and use it as a reference for the permissions on files under `.git`. But I think you've lost information, and without an upstream repo or backup you won't be able to get it back.

Comment: @KeithThompson: it seems that I've hit Control-C before anything bad had a chance to happen (see below). The command I've used was `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/a/b/g'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Fix `.git/config`. The only thing I can imagine causing permission denied error editing the commit log is invalid editor setting
2. Check the permissions. It might still be different issue.
3. Do a `git fsck` on the repository. If it gives you errors, it's probably not recoverable and you need to get another copy of the repository (re-clone upstream, restore backup etc.)
4. If you are really desperate, try undoing the transformation to all the files fsck will declare bad. You'll have to try all possible combinations if there is ambiguity. At least you can be certain you undid the change correctly when fsck stops listing the file.

Comment: Everything worked before the change. git fsck displays this: `bad sha1 file: .git/objects/14/sedSFdz2t6)` and some dangling trees.

Comment: @user2656304: If you are really desperate, try undoing the transformation on that file. If there is more than one match, you'll have to try all combinations. If you get it to stop saying that, you've fixed the repository.

Comment: Could it be that `sedSFdz2t6` is just a leftover temporary file from running sed on all files? I've moved it out of the directory and now `git fsck` only displays information about dangling trees (what does it mean? I'm new to git).

Comment: I did `git reset` a few times, could this be the cause? Am I safe now?

Comment: (if that's the case, how do I make it let me commit again?)

Comment: @user2656304: You are right, `sedSFdz2t6` is a sed temporary file and you can delete it. All git files in that directory should be named by 38 hex digit strings. `git reset` only undoes changes to the working tree, but you need to make sure your repository is not damaged first. You need to get `git fsck` to pass.

Comment: `git fsck` only displays information about dangling trees now.

Comment: @user2656304: Dangling trees should not be a problem. Than you have another problem with permissions. Make sure you can start the editor you have configured for git and make sure you can edit the file it's listing in the error in commit. If the platform is Windows, it may also be a hanging process keeping the file open, in which case the easiest remedy is a restart (or get Process Explorer from Microsoft site and use it to hunt down the process).

Comment: The write permission was not set for files in .git even though I made a few commits today, weird. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repository and move the `.git` directory to folder with the issue.

```
git clone repo-address tmp-dir
mv tmp-dir/.git issue-dir
rm -rf tmp-dir
```

Where `issue-dir` is your directory.